# How can I implement an onComplete function with CSS trasforms in webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using some CSS transitions like the following:

```
.slide_left {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0px,0px);
}
```

I'd like to have a javascript callback function that runs when this transition is complete. I've seen hints of it on the web, but I can't find docs or examples anywhere. Has somebody out there done this successfully?

Right now, I'm using a setTimeout to guess at the duration, but it's clunkier than I want it to be.

Thanks!

---

Solution: (thanks kprevas!)

In the snippet below, when the "Detail" div is shown, the "whole_display" div slides left to reveal it. When hidden, the whole_display slides right to hide it. This is written with JQuery and tested on Safari 5.0.3.

```
<style type="text/css">
.slide_left {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0px,0px);
}
.slide_right {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}
</style>

<script type="text/javscript">
function clearDetail() {
    $("#whole_display").get(0).addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', finishClearPlanDetail);
    $("#whole_display").removeClass("slide_left")
    $("#whole_display").addClass("slide_right")

}

function finishClearDetail(event) {
    $("#whole_display").removeClass("slide_right"); 
    $("#whole_display").get(0).removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', finishClearPlanDetail);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "webkitTransitionEnd" event.

```
box.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) {
  alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
}, false );
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/AnimatingCSSTransitions/AnimatingCSSTransitions.html

Answer (score 1):

Also use `removeEventlistener('webkitTransitionEnd',calee,false)`
when you want to  remove this added event. Else it will be triggred every time the DOM element is applied some animation.